# Как определить основание системы счисления числа?1

Tags: математика, системы-счисления, информатика

180 в 10 системе счисления = 1210 в х системе счисления, как найти х? если можно то попродобнее

Answer (score 3):

`1210` в системе счисления `x` значит решить уравнение:

```
1 * x^3  +  2 * x^2  +  1 * x  +  0  =  180
```

или

```
          x * (x^2  +  2 * x  +  1)  =  180
```

или

```
                      x * (x + 1)^2  =  180
```

Как

```
180 = 5 * 6^2
```

вы сразу видите результат (`5`).

(Оператор `^` здес значит степень: `x^3` - третья степень от `x`.)

Comment: как внезапно  x * (x + 1)^2 превратилось в 5 * 6^2 ))

Comment: Разложением `180` на простые множители: `2^2 * 3^2 * 5`.

Comment: Таки а причем `значит решить уравнение:`  и  `Разложением 180 на простые множители`? тогда смысл решать уравнение, если достаточно число разложить? А если бы число было 129736128351364? Как в этом случае будет решаться X^14? Не проще ли просто подобрать систему счисления?

Comment: @АлексейШиманский: Например, можно убедиться, что 5 подходит, и заметить, что `x * (x + 1)^2` монотонно возрастает при положительном `x`, а значит, других решений нет.

Comment: @VladD просто в ответе никак не упоминается ни о чем и резко переходит от одного к другому, что несколько сбивает с толку. Но в целом это довольно простой пример. В более сложных - это будет менее эффективно и более запутанно

Comment: @АлексейШиманский: Ну в общем случае будет тоже возрастающий полином, поэтому всегда достаточно «угадать» корень. Например, найти верхнюю и нижнюю границы подстановками, и перебрать.